# Which buildings increase your population cap?

Tags: the-settlers-online

The population cap affects how many soldiers you can have, but which buildings (other than the standard residence and noble residence) increase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging on my own, and eventually found out the following:

- Your Mayor's House gives you a small amount of population capacity (the starting cap), but you don't get more by upgrading it.
- Gingerbread Houses (a reward from the 2015 Christmas event) have 150% of the capacity of a Noble Residence, and similarly scaled upgrade costs.
- A Pirate residence gives +50 pop cap, but cannot be upgraded.
- A White Castle (sometimes a reward for completing the adventure Stealing from the Rich) gives +50 pop cap and also cannot be upgraded.
- A Dark Castle gives +100 population cap and can't be upgraded. It's a very rare reward for the adventure The Black Knights.
- A Witch Tower gives +100 population cap and can't be upgraded. It is a possible reward from the adventures The Dark Brotherhood and Roaring Bull.
- A Frozen Manor gives +140 pop cap (the most of any one building) and also can't be upgraded. It is only available from the Master Architect Mystery Chest.
- Floating Residences act as Noble Residences, except they have +10 population capacity (they can be upgraded, and will always have 10 more population than an equivalent level Noble Residence) which gives them 40-80 pop cap boost, depending on level. They can only be built over water, which saves space on your island. They can be bought for 290 gems each (200 more than a Noble Residence deed) from the Architect in the Merchant Chest.